# Module compatibility between major Drupal versions

Tags: 7

I am planning to use Drift chat on Drupal website, which is built in Drupal 7.

I could see Drift modules only for Drupal 8? Will this work with Drupal 7 as well?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer given by No Sssweat is correct and therefore should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this work with Drupal 7 as well?

Nope. D7 and D8 are vastly different under the hood; therefore, there is no backward and no forward compatibility across Core versions. If there are none for D7 you will have to build one or upgrade your site to D8 if you see fit.

Comment: Means Drift module for D7 is not available?

Comment: @GauravG correct

Comment: Can you please suggest me best chat bot for D7?

Comment: @GauravG I haven't used any chat bot, so I can't suggest you one.